# Topological operations corresponding to abelianization of the fundamental group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

$\newcommand{\ab}{\mathrm{ab}}$Suppose we have a topological space $X$ with a non-abelian fundamental group  $\pi_1(X)$. We'd like to perform a sequence of topological operations on $X$ (for example, filling in holes) to arrive at a space $X^{\ab}$ whose fundamental group is the abelianization of $X$: $\pi_1(X^{\ab}) = \pi_1(X)^{\ab}$.

What is this procedure called? What are the operations involved? Can this always be done in a systematic manner?

I'd like to know how many homotopically distinct $X^{\ab}$ we'd get in this way, expressed in terms of some measure of complexity of $\pi_1(X)$.

Ultimately, I'd like a description of the topological simplification along all the steps of the derived series of $\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: It's not exactly abelianization, but you might be interested in Quillen's +-construction. You can of course always add cells to $X$ to kill commutators in $\pi_1$, but I don't know if you'd like something more explicit (note that the +-construction is not that much more explicit, although it has a nice homotopical universal property)

Comment: You could form the Eilenberg-MacLane space $X^{ab}= K(H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}),1)$, but this probably isn't the only choice satisfying your requirements.

Comment: [Here's a related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193491/is-there-a-simplification-functor-in-algebraic-topology/193495).

Comment: To elaborate on Maxime's message, Quillen's plus construction is not the universal map making the fundamental group abelian, but it is the universal map making the fundamental group *hypoabelian*, and in fact this often produces already the abelianization

Comment: The canonical example of this is taking the infinite symmetric product of X, or the free topological abelian group on X: the Dold-Thom theorem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dold%E2%80%93Thom_theorem